# How i make a Addition from 2 tables and insert the value to one of them

Tags: java, sql-server

I cant find the right query that make an addition from 2 tables 2 columns inserts and save the data to one of them

Here is my makeorderaction

```
 private void Make_OrderActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
     String query="INSERT INTO Orders(Pro_Id ,Pro_Name,Order_Quantity,Order_Date)VALUES ('"+Pro_Id.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Name.getText()+" ','"+Order_Quantity.getText()+" ','"+Order_Date.getText()+" ') ";
    executeSQLQuery(query,"Inserted");
    String qquery ="UPDATE Products SET Pro_Quantity where Prod_Id = Pro_Quantity+Order_Quantity ";
    // executeSQLQuery(query,"quantity updated");
    }
```

I need to find a sqlquery that make addition from table Order the column Order_Quantity with the table products the  column Pro_Quantity. And  make an  update in table products the new value in column Pro_Quantity depending each time the identifier of the product any idea  ? Ty

Table Orders

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
    [Order_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Order_Date] [int] NULL,
    [Order_Quantity] [int] NULL,
    [Pro_Id] [int] NULL,
    [Pro_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__Orders__F1E4607B714E3A74] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Order_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Orders_Products] FOREIGN KEY([Pro_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Products] ([Pro_Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Orders_Products]
GO
```

Table Products

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [Pro_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Pro_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Pro_Price] [float] NULL,
    [Pro_Quantity] [int] NULL,
    [Pro_Supplier_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Pro_Tax] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Cat_products] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Pro_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

I add this qquery but i think he need some changes

```
  String qquery=  " UPDATE Products SET Pro_Quantity= Pro_Quantity + '"+Order_Quantity.getText()+"' FROM Products  INNER JOIN Orders ON   Products.Pro_Id="+Orders.getText() ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i change the above code a bit so he update the last order only.

```
String query= "  UPDATE Products SET Pro_Quantity= Products.Pro_Quantity + Orders.Order_Quantity FROM Products INNER JOIN Orders ON Products.Pro_Id= Orders.Pro_Id where Order_Id = (SELECT MAX(Order_Id) FROM Orders)" ; 
        executeSQLQuery(query,"updated");
```

Answer (score 1):

some think like this
[How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

```
    UPDATE P
SET
    P.Pro_Quantity= P.Pro_Quantity + O.Order_Quantity       
FROM
    Products as P
    INNER JOIN Orders as O
        ON P.Pro_Id= O.Pro_Id
```

Comment: so in my query it should be something like that?                                            String qquery= " UPDATE Products SET Pro_Quantity= Products.Pro_Quantity + Orders.Orders FROM Products  INNER JOIN Orders ON Products.Pro_Id= Orders.Pro_Id";

Comment: yes make a try, I'm not sure that is work without alias.

Comment: try the query in a SQL client

Comment: ok when i run this query  i get a message (2 row(s) affected)  but nothing really change

Comment: It depends of your data, maybe you have 0 quantity in order, or it need to be committed.

Comment: in makeorder function i insert a value in order quantity so my table has values but isnt add them in addition in product quantity column

Comment: in product table quantities are 0 or null ?

Comment: I made test on my sqlserver I correct the query and check that is working

Comment: maybe he need something else in netbeans java  ? cause in sql he works but he cant give results cause the value order_qyantity is given when i press the button make order so untill then he has zero pro_id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123432/discussion-between-george-kontonikolaou-and-mr-thorynque).